# Why does this Makefile rebuild every time?

Tags: python, c++, makefile

I have a Makefile to build some simple Python bindings. Unfortunately, upon a plain `make` or `make all` it will rebuild every time, even when `py11_bindings.cpp` was not changed. I checked whether maybe the source file would accidentally be touched or something, but that's not the case as far as I see.

```
PYTHON = /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/bin
CPP = c++
INC = -I/software/pybind11/include -I/software/eigen
PYTHONCFG = `$(PYTHON)/python3.5-config --cflags --ldflags`
SRC = py11_bindings.cpp
TARGET = _chain.so

all: $(SRC)
    $(CPP) -O3 -shared -std=c++11 $(INC) $(PYTHONCFG) $^ -o $(TARGET)

clean:
    rm $(TARGET)
```

I have absolutely no clue why this should happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a makefile expert, so maybe I am not using the correct terms.

However: Your `all:` defines to create the source file, when it should list the targets to create. Then you should, for each target, list the dependencies and describe, how to create it.

So, your makefile should look like this:

```
all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET) : $(SRC)
    $(CPP) -O3 -shared -std=c++11 $(INC) $(PYTHONCFG) $^ -o $(TARGET)
```

Comment: And add `.PHONY: all clean`.

Comment: Sorry, no, does not help. The same will happen when I change my makefile to your suggestion.

Comment: @Michael Post your updated code and also the output of `make -rd`.

Comment: @MaximEgorushkin: It actually works now, probably I made another stupid mistake before. Sorry for the confusion.